# Call a Python 2.7 module in Python 3.2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess, arcpy

I have a GUI program that I have developed in Python 3.2 to extract various geospatial data products. I need to call a module I have developed in Python 2.7.

I am looking for a way to be able to call the Python 2.7 code using a Python 2.7 interpreter inside of Python 3.2 program. I cannot port the 2.7 to Python 3.2 as it uses a Python version installed with ESRI ArcMap and relies on the arcpy module which is not available for Python 3. My only idea right now would be to use subprocess to call the module as a batch process however this is a bit messy and I would prefer the two programs had some relationship.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `subprocess.check_output(['C:\\python27\\python.exe', 'yourModule.py'])`

If you want to call a specific function within the 27 file, you can use more system arguments. The call would look like:

```
subprocess.check_output(['C:\\python27\\python.exe', 'yourModule.py', 'funcName'])
```

And in the 27 file you can add:

```
import sys
if __name__=='__main__':
    if 'funcName' in sys.argv:
        funcName()
     else:
        #... execute normally
```

Comment: Do you know of anyway I could call a specific function of this python file with arguments?

Comment: Although I never originally intended to use subprocess this does do the job as expected, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You could spawn the python 2.7 process as a server handling RPC requests from your GUI running on 3.2. That will work either over the network, or local pipes, or shared memory, or your system's message bus, or many other ways. You just need to translate your library's API into some kind of serialised messages.

Let's say your library has a function: (super simplified example)

```
def add(a, b):
    return a+b
```

You'd wrap this in some server, let's say a [flask app](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/), which does:

```
@app.route("/add", methods=["POST"])
def handle_add():
    data = request.get_json()
    ret = your_lib.add(data['a'], data['b'])
    return jsonify(ret)
```

and on the client side, send and unpack the values using something like [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

You could even make it fairly transparent by implementing a translator module with methods named the same as the library itself and doing `import your_http_wrapper as your_library_name`.

The trick now is to make sure all your parameters can be serialised and that you can realistically send all the arguments/return values in a reasonable time on each call. Also, you lose the ability to change the contents of the variables you pass to the wrapper, because the server will modify only the local copy (unless you implement serialising all those modifications as well)

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat late but in case someone stumbles over this thread:

I've written a [module](https://github.com/maxfischer2781/cpy2py) that transparently runs parts of a program in other python interpreters. Basically it provides decorators and base classes that replace functions and objects with proxies that interface with other interpreters.

It's intended for compatibility, e.g. running `python2` only code in `python3`, or accessing C modules from `pypy`.

In the following example, the loop runs 4x as fast via using `pypy` as it would with plain `python`.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
from cpy2py import TwinMaster, twinfunction
import sys
import time
import math


# loops in PyPy
@twinfunction('pypy')
def prime_sieve(max_val):
    start_time = time.time()
    primes = [1] * 2 + [0] * (max_val - 1)
    for value, factors in enumerate(primes):
        if factors == 0:
            for multiple in xrange(value*value, max_val + 1, value):
                primes[multiple] += 1
    return {'xy': [
        [primes[idx] == 0 for idx in range(minidx, minidx + int(math.sqrt(max_val)))]
        for minidx in range(0, max_val, int(math.sqrt(max_val)))
        ], 'info': '%s in %.1fs' % (sys.executable, time.time() - start_time)}


# matplotlib in CPython
@twinfunction('python')
def draw(xy, info='<None>'):
    from matplotlib import pyplot
    pyplot.copper()
    pyplot.matshow(xy)
    pyplot.xlabel(info, color="red")
    pyplot.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    twins = [TwinMaster('python'), TwinMaster('pypy')]
    for twin in twins:
        twin.start()
    data = prime_sieve(int(1E6))
    draw(**data)
```

Comment: yet to use this however it looks very useful, thanks!